# Procedimiento almacenado para mostrar datos sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, visual-studio, stored-procedure

Mi duda es la siguiente:

Estoy creando un programa el cual un usuario pueda ver sus mismos datos, como una consulta a su perfil.
Quiero saber como podría hacer el procedimiento almacenado para mostrar esto sin que reciba ningún parámetro, ya que siento que seria algo ilógico que el usuario luego de haber iniciado sesión tenga que volver a escribir su usuario para que le muestre sus datos.

De momento lo que tengo es esto, me da problema porque mi procedimiento almacenado espera que le retorne el usuario pero no termino de entender como capturarlo en el momento en que inicia sesión el usuario.

```
try
                {
                    SqlConnection conex = new SqlConnection(ConexString);
                    conex.Open();
                    SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("SP_CONSULTA_DATOS_CLIENTE", conex);
                    comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    //comando.Parameters.Add(Session["USERNAME"]);
                    SqlDataReader lector = comando.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                    DataTable tabla = new DataTable();
                    tabla.Load(lector);
                    conex.Close();

                    txtID_Usurario.Text = tabla.Rows[0][1].ToString();
                    txtUsuario.Text = tabla.Rows[0][2].ToString();
                    txtNombres.Text = tabla.Rows[0][3].ToString();
                    txtApellido.Text = tabla.Rows[0][4].ToString();
                    txtDireccion.Text = tabla.Rows[0][5].ToString();
                    txtTelefono.Text = tabla.Rows[0][6].ToString();
                    txtCorreo.Text = tabla.Rows[0][7].ToString();
            }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    lblInfo.Text = ex.ToString();
                }
```

Comment: Hola Ricardo, podrías detallar la relación de tus tablas y los campos que quisieras mostrar? O todo se encuentra en la tabla usuario? Saludos!

Comment: Lo que quisiera mostrar son todos los datos de la tabla usuarios, ahorita agrego la imagen de la tabla.

Comment: por el momento no tengo una respuesta concreta a tu problema, pero podría ser que al loguearse la persona se guarde (voy a suponer que estas haciendo esta aplicación con html) el id en alguna variable. Ya cuando le de click en "Ver perfil" tome esta id y cargue los datos correspondientes

Comment: Cómo podría guardar esa variable para utilizarla como tú dices? La aplicación la estoy haciendo en asp.net

Comment: Eso lo deberías de hacer en ASP.NET. Ya que el usuario se logueó, tendrías que guardar sus credenciales para futuras consultas a la BD. Podrías manejar el objeto Session, quizá te ayude este link [Session](https://www.guru99.com/asp-net-session-management.html)

Comment: Lo que podrías hacer es usar un sp para loguearte y otro sp para consultar esa info, el primer sp que te devuelva el id del usuario logueado, y posteriormente guardas ese id en una variable de session como te comenta @CarlosPozos, para después el otro sp reciba como parámetro ese id y te devuelva la info del usuario.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, estaba revisando el código y al parecer ya capturaba la variable sin darme cuenta.
Me sirvió mucho el enlace @CarlosPozos, gracias